# How to import existing Java.class Files to Android Studio Project

Tags: file, android-studio, import, module

I need to know how I can properly add existing Java.class files to an Android Studio Project. My goal is to use these classes in an Android Project.

The Class Files are already written in Eclipse for another Java Project.

I've already tried `File->New->New Module->selecting Java Library->Finish` but that doesn't work properly.

As you probably all know it makes the `MyClass` Class by default.
For testing I imported `com.example.*` in my `MainActivity` and tried to build an Object of that Class inside the `onCreate()` Method.

The problem is it can't compile the Project. I got the following Errors:

```
Error:(7, 1) error: package com.example does not exist
Error:(16, 9) error: cannot find symbol class MyClass
Note: C:\Users\...\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Can anybody explain how to import my `Java.class` files correctly so that I can use them in my project?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: @Sausagedioxide : Posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add as a `local library package` to your project in `Android Studio`.

- In android `Project` window, right click on `app` and select `New -> Module`.
- In the `Create New Module` window, select `Java Library` and click `next`. Then give the module name, for example `HttpClient` in `Library Name` field. Then give `Java package name` as same as your existing package `com.example.xxx`. Then give one existing class file name `AnyFileName` in `Java Class Name` field.
- Now new module is created with the name `HttpClient` and the package name is `com.example.xxx`. With an empty class file `Anyfilename.java`
- Now copy all your `.java` files to the `HttpClient` folder created inside your android project. Now it would have overwritten the empty file `Anyfilename.java` also.
- After copying all `.java` files would have automatically added to the library module.
- And you will get 3rd `build.gradle` file for your module. Already you might be having 2 `build.gradle` for your android project.
- In your app's `build.gradle` file, include local library [dependency](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html) `compile project(":HttpClient")`. Now you can import java files in `HttpClient` module to android app's java files.

Note : Above information is given based on Android Studio 2.3.3